# How to format cells as weight in grams but removing insignificant decimal point and places?

Tags: google-sheets, decimal, rounding

I have a sheet with values that I want to format in grams. The values range from high to low and I wish to format them with a comma as a thousand-separator, and rounded to two decimal places, but trimming both the decimal point and places where the number is a whole number. The following examples should explain better:

1. 1000 to be presented as 1,000g
2. 0.75 to be presented as 0.75g
3. 0.2 to be presented as 0.2g
4. 0.1234 to be presented as 0.12g

I've tried using a custom number format of **#,##0.##g** but this does not satisfy my first requirement (a) where the numbers are whole numbers and leaves an insignificant decimal point (i.e. 1,000.g), although does very well at formatting the remaining three requirements (b, c and d).

Is there a way of overcoming this?

Answer (score 2):

```
#,##0.00_ g;(#,##0.00 g)
```

I'm a bit late to this article but I found the above format works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are in column A with a header. You could try putting this in B2 then hide column A:

```
=arrayformula(if(arrayformula(TRUNC(A2:A,2)&"g")="0g","",arrayformula(TRUNC(A2:A,2)&"g")))
```

The best I could do with format was [=0]0;.## It gets rid of the period in 1000 but does not truncate 0.1234 and doesn't add the g. Maybe you could work with that if you must use format. I really don't think format can do it.